# Generate models via rails console (programmatically)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**UPDATED:**

I have been successful in generating controllers/models via rails console

```
Rails::Generators.invoke("controller" ,["pages"], behavior: :invoke)

Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model" ,["page"], behavior: :invoke)
```

*But still* no luck for generating migration for creating table. I have tried this 
`Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:migration" ,["create",["text:text"]], behavior: :invoke)`

but it creates empty migration file.

Comment: Try `Rails::Generators.invoke("active_record:model" ,["page"], behavior: :invoke)`

Comment: yes, it creates model but not migration file, How it can be done??

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397925/how-to-generate-create-table-migration-file-using-railsgenerators-invokeacti